# "Neither" and "either" usage in negative sentence

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, negation

I would like to make sure I understood the usage of these:

*Do you want A or B?*

> 1. I do not want either. [none of them]
> 2. I want neither. [Can I say that?]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I do not want either.

and

> I want neither.

are both fine.

*Neither* is the negative form of *either*.

Comment: can I say "I don't want A, and I don't want B either"?

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways you could express your sentiments:

```
I don't want either.
I don't want either of them.
I want neither.
I want neither of them.
I want neither A nor B.
```

But I would not use:

```
I don't want either A or B.
```

(That's what *neither* is for.)

If, after declining A and B, you were then offered C, D, or E, you could say:

```
I don't want C, D, or E.
I don't want any of those.
I want none of those options.
I want neither C, nor D, nor E.
I don't want either C, D, or E.
```

("*I don't want either...*" sounds more acceptable with *more than* two elements, as opposed to *just* two elements, which is why I opted to include it among the possibilities here, but recommended against its use in the previous example.)

Still, you would **not** say:

```
I don't want neither C, D, nor E.
```

because that forms a double negative, which is not used in Standard English.

Lastly, as Martin B pointed out, the word *either* has two meanings.  It can be used either as a word that *introduces two alternatives*, or as a word that *indicates similarities with a statement just made*.  So, in the scenario just described, you could also say:

```
I don't want C, D, or E, either.
I don't want any of those, either. 
I want none of those options, either.
None of those options appeal to me, either.
```

but in those four cases, *either* is being used in its other context, and is roughly equivalent *also* or *as well*.

Comment: @jwpat7: Yes to both cases. I meant Martin B, and Standard English.  Thanks for pointing that out; I've made the edits.

Comment: This post triggered this https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i-dont-want-either-a-or-b.2710342/ discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You can say either

> I don't want either of them.

or

> I want neither A nor B.

*Either* indicates a choice between two alternatives. *Neither* combines two negative ideas.

Often with *neither* you repeat the options, joining them with *nor*.

Comment: "I don't want them either" has a different meaning than "I do not want either". The former means there is another person who does not want an indefinite number of things in question, and you also do not want them. The latter means that there are exactly two things in question, and you want neither one nor the other of them.

Comment: @MartinB: Good point; well explained.  I've edited the answer to reflect your comment.