# Either or Neither in sentence with another negative

Tags: negation, neither-nor, negative-polarity-items, either-or

I am writing something where I want to say the following:

> I have never visited either Scotland (n)or England.

I couldn't find information about this on either this site (n)or any other site on Google, including the [other](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/60840/92713) [questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/186875/92713) I found on this site, to answer this question specifically. Most other sources never touch on this subject with a negative already in the sentence somewhere else.

As far as I understand, *nor* should only occur in combination with *neither*, so in that case my sentence should have *or*, but I'm not completely sure if that's correct.

Comment: "I have never visited Scotland or England"  - "I have visited neither Scotland nor England."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not true that *nor* can only occur in sentences that also involve *neither*. But this is still quite a different proposition from trying to pair it up as  *either..nor* instead of as *neither..nor*.

Consider this valid sentence and why it works:

> I have never visited England, nor have I ever visited Scotland either.

Please see [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/106796/2085) for copious citations from the OED, literature, and other sources including:

> > - But it was never published (though some indication of its content could be gleaned from *The Lord of the Rings*), and throughout my father’s long life he never abandoned it, nor ceased even in his last years to work on it.
> > - I could not find her, nor even the crimson-shot orange disk of the old sun.
> > - And he would never walk, nor fly, nor be a knight.
> > - It has never been that way, nor is it now.

Most speakers today would say:

> I have never visited England or Scotland.

But you could also get away with writing:

> I’ve been to Wales a few times before via the quick jaunt across the Irish Sea, yet to this date I have never visited England — nor Scotland, come to think of it.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation! For brevity, I think I'll go for the first one, but I'll use this advice for similar situations I might encounter.